# This webpage has a redirect loop - Wordpress + custom rewrites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to run a site that routes all URI requests through an index.php file for processing, but I'm also trying to run Wordpress at the webroot. Everything works fine, except for requests to https://mysite.com/wp-admin/, which gives me a "This webpage has a redirect loop" error.  Going to https://mysite.com/wp-admin/edit.php works fine.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# eliminate www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1 [R,L]

RewriteBase /

# rewrite directory patterns
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-%/\/]+)/([0-9]+)$    /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3  [NC,QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-%/\/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2    [NC,QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1  [NC,QSA,L] 

# Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas what's causing the redirect loop? I've tried putting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
```

in front of the force SSL and eliminate www rules, but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Try replacing "https" with "http" in the first RewriteRule. Don't understand why is forcing SSL just to remove www. I am guessing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin - [L]
```

Add this rule at the top, above all other rules.

Comment: Brilliant and obvious, now that I look at it. Thanks so much.